# Appropriately choosing the parameter so that one function maximizes while other minimizes

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose we have two functions $f$ and $g$ of some variables $x,y,z\in R$. Our goal is to appropriately choose the values of  $x,y,z$ such that $f$ is maximized while $g$ is minimized.

Here, I am not sure how to appropriately apply maxima-minima (partial derivatives) techniques so that we could compute the required result.

Comment: Well, it need not exist, e.g. if $f=g$. And if we know a priori that such a simultaneous extremum does exist, is there some reason we can't find the maxima of $f$, find the minima of $g$, and look for points in both sets?

Comment: You might try to maximize $f-g.$ That gives one answer of when $(x,y,z)$ is better that $(x',y',z').$ Without such a criterion all you can say is that you don't want to pick a place if there is another with a bigger $f$ and $g$ no bigger.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz Thanks for your comment! To be more specific, $f$ and $g$ are probabilities of two events, over the same set of random variables. Our goal is to choose values of random variables such that $f$ is maximized while $g$ is minimized.